# Discord.py On Message Sending Infinite Messages

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands

with open('config.json', 'r') as config:
    config = json.load(config)

token = config['token']
prefix = config['prefix']

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith == 'hi' or 'Hi':
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)

client.run(token)
```

And I Had Typed hi Once And It Spammed Hello And After Reopening It Still Spammed Hello Is There Any Way To Fix This?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your bot is spamming "hello" is it's responding to itself. A simple way can be used to fix this which checks if the user is a bot, if so it would just return and simply nothing would happen if a bot said "hello"

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if message.content.startswith == 'hi' or 'Hi':
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Here I have added `message.author.bot`, this would check if the user is a bot or not, or if the bot is responding to itself and prevent spamming.

Comment: `str.startswith` it's a method, not attribute

Comment: That’s would not happen. The bot only send “Hello”. It is because of the ‘if’ condition that causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It’s sending an infinite number of messages because your conditional is incorrect. The first comparison is `message.content.startswith() == ‘hi’`, which will always be `False` (stick your string in the parentheses). The second is `’Hi’` which will always be `True`, since it is not an empty string.

Correct your condition to `if message.content.startswith(‘hi’) or message.content.startswith(‘Hi’):` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic Python problem. `if message.content.startswith == 'hi' or 'Hi':` doesn't means:

> if (message content is either hi or Hi)

It means:

> if (message content is hi) or (Hi)

In this case, **Hi** will always return `True`. That's why your bot is spamming messages.

You can prevent this by variant ways. But the best way to fix this is using `str.lower()`

Also, you cannot use `str.startswith()` function like that. You have to type the string inside the parentheses.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith('hi'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```